# Create an inventory for a python game

Tags: python, oop, pygame

So I try to create an inventory for the python game Dodger. In the inventory I want to be able to select different players to play the game. But when I run the game, only the option images/player.png is chosen. How can I fix that? thanks
This is what I have tried so far:
//Inventory.py

```
import pygame
import pygwidgets
import pyghelpers
import random
from Player import Player
import Constants
from Constants import *

class Inventory(pyghelpers.Scene):

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.player = Player(window)
        self.player0 = pygwidgets.CustomButton(self.window, (30, 250), 'images/player_inv.png')
        self.player1 = pygwidgets.CustomButton(self.window, (280, 250), 'images/player1_inv.jpg')
        self.player2 = pygwidgets.CustomButton(self.window, (30, 450), 'images/char1_inv.png')
        self.inventory = []
        self.image = pygwidgets.Image(self.window,(0, 0),'images/inventory.png')

        self.quitButton = pygwidgets.CustomButton(self.window,
                                                  (30, 650),
                                                  up='images/quitNormal.png',
                                                  down='images/quitDown.png',
                                                  over='images/quitOver.png',
                                                  disabled='images/quitDisabled.png')

        self.backButton = pygwidgets.CustomButton(self.window,
                                                  (240, 650),
                                                  up='images/backNormal.png',
                                                  down='images/backDown.png',
                                                  over='images/backOver.png',
                                                  disabled='images/backDisabled.png')

    def getSceneKey(self):
        return SCENE_INVENTORY

    def enter(self, data):
        pass

    def handleInputs(self, eventsList, keyPressedList):
        for event in eventsList:
            if self.quitButton.handleEvent(event):
                self.quit()

            elif self.backButton.handleEvent(event):
                self.goToScene(Constants.SCENE_PLAY)

            if self.player0.handleEvent(event):
                self.player.imagelink = 'images/player.png'
                self.goToScene(Constants.SCENE_PLAY)

            elif self.player1.handleEvent(event):
                self.player.imagelink = 'images/player1.jpg'
                self.goToScene(Constants.SCENE_PLAY)

            elif self.player2.handleEvent(event):
                self.player.imagelink = 'images/player2.png'
                self.goToScene(Constants.SCENE_PLAY)

    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        self.image.draw()
        self.quitButton.draw()
        self.backButton.draw()
        self.player0.draw()
        self.player1.draw()
        self.player2.draw()
```

//Player.py

```
import pygame
import pygwidgets
from Constants import *

class Player():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.imagelink = 'images/player.png'
        self.image = pygwidgets.Image(window,
                                (-100, -100), self.imagelink)
        playerRect = self.image.getRect()
        self.maxX = WINDOW_WIDTH - playerRect.width
        self.maxY = GAME_HEIGHT - playerRect.height

    # Every frame, move the Player icon to the mouse position
    # Limits the x- and y-coordinates to the game area of the window
    def update(self, x, y):
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        elif x > self.maxX:
            x = self.maxX
        if y < 0:
            y = 0
        elif y > self.maxY:
            y = self.maxY

        self.image.setLoc((x, y))
        return self.image.getRect()

    def draw(self):
        self.image.draw()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of55i.png)

Answer (score 1):

With your code `Player.imagelink = 'images/player1.jpg'`, you are modifying a *class attribute* and not a *class instance attribute*. You can fix this by changing `self.player.imagelink = 'images/player1.jpg'`. You will need to make similar changes for each line that includes `Player.imagelink = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have tried to change the code, but it still does not work. The player I choose in the inventory is not the same as the player in the imagelink in class Player. Here is my code so far: (updated in the code above)